# Flutter build AAR targeting dev and prod flavors (build variants)

Tags: flutter

I have set up different build variants like dev and staging and production.

I run local debug mode with command- `flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart`
similarly, the production build command

```
- flutter build --apk -t lib/main_prod.dart --release
```

But AAR builds `flutter build aar -t lib/main_prod.dart --release` doesn't work?

is anything extra work needed for AAR builds?

Comment: I'm having this issue also